# Merging stylesheets and javascript files into 1 on the server side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, vb.net

I like to have seperate javascript files and css files in my web projects. Each pages has its own javascript and css file for the sake of clarity on my behalf.

In my latest project I ended up having 10 seperate stylesheets and 9 javascript files and that slows down my application.

My question: whats the fastest way of merging all stylesheets into 1 file and all javascripts into one file on the server side? In the end the browser should see it as 1 file but I like to keep my files seperate on the back end.

Thanks!

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've used in the past: http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/

Comment: Looks good. But it does more than I actually need. Its not only combining the files but its also compressing them. And you need to re-run the tool after each modification. Right?

Comment: @kay10 That's true. As for rerunning, you just set it up as a post-build event.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using combres right now. This tool uses combining and minification throuhg the yuicompressor.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at using MSBuild to do this at build time.

These articles might help:

http://blog.lupi-software.com/2011/05/16/minifying-css-and-javascript-automatically-in-asp-net/

[Combining javascript and css files with Rejuicer in ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9302821/combining-javascript-and-css-files-with-rejuicer-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: I couldnt get rejuicer to work. Combres works like a charm (also suggested in that post).